# How to call postgres position() function in jpa query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm want to retreive posts from database ordered by ids given in `IN` operator

I'm using below spring data JPA query to get posts from database, but postgres is not respecting order of rows specified in given `postIds` list in result and returning result ordered by `postId` descending (or ascending, doesn't matter)

```
@Query("SELECT p from Post p where p.postId in (:postIds))
fun findPostByIdIn(postIds: List<Long>): List<Post>
```

To maintain order of result, i could use this query

```
SELECT p from posts p where p.post_id in (10000442, 10000436, 10000440) ORDER BY POSITION(post_id::text IN '10000442, 10000436, 10000440');
```

My question is, how can i use `position()` function (which is standard postgresql function) from jpa query with given params? Do i must need to use native query? If so, how can i use native query in spring boot ?
I've tried below query but both of them are not working

```
@Query(
        "SELECT p from posts p where p.post_id in (:postIds) ORDER BY POSITION(p.post_id::text IN ':postIds')",
        nativeQuery = true
    )

@Query(
        "SELECT p from posts p where p.post_id in (:postIds) ORDER BY POSITION(p.post_id\\:\\:text IN ':postIds')",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
It says ` The column name post_id was not found in this ResultSet.`
```

Comment: `@Query("SELECT p.* from posts p where p.post_id in (:postIds) AND p.expire_at >= now() ORDER BY POSITION(p.post_id\\:\\:text IN ':postIds')", nativeQuery = true)
fun findNonExpiredPostByIdIn(postIds: List<Long>): List<Post>`
This query works without error, but its sorted by postId in ascending order, not in provided order in list

Answer (score 0):

Try to make List<Object[]> as return type instead of List then check result content to analyze the issue.

Comment: There's nothing to analyze, it says ailed to execute query. However, i've posted on query in comment to my question,